# C++ Conditional operator with different types as arguments

Tags: c++, pointers, conditional-operator

I'm trying to use the conditional operator (?) on an int and a *node (node being a custom struct). Here's my code, and the resulting error.

node:

```
struct node {
  int num;
  node *next;
};
```

conditional implementation:

```
void PrintNodes(node *head_p) {
  int done = 0;
  while (!done) {
    PrintNodeData(head_p);
    // if (head_p->next==NULL) {
    //   done++;
    // } else {
    //   head_p++;
    // }
    ((head_p->next==NULL) ? done : head_p)++;
  }
}
```

I have the equivalent `if...then...else` statement in comments above the conditional statement, I just want to be able to trim it down to one line.

## EDIT

The error:

```
test.cc: In function ‘void PrintNodes(node*)’:
test.cc:28:36: error: operands to ?: have different types ‘int’ and ‘node*’
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: And the resulting error is...?

Comment: *Why* do you want to trim it down to one line?

Comment: This is very ugly, think about something better

Comment: Because I like having small simple functions, and I didn't think it made it _too_ difficult to read.

Comment: @JShoe You were wrong.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Okay. I'll defer.

Comment: Do you actually want `head_p++` rather than `head_p = head_p->next`? If you're iterating over a linked list, the the "small simple" way to do it is `for (; head_p; head_p=head_p->next) PrintNodeData(head_p);`

Comment: Is there an actual difference?

Comment: @JShoe: A difference between incrementing a pointer, and reading a different pointer? Yes, there's a huge difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that! The conditional operator wants two operands that have the same type or "compatible" types (that is, one can be implicitly converted to the other). But here your operands are of types `int` and `node*` (and moreover you're trying to use the result as an lvalue for `++`, so we could say that the types are `int&` and `node*&`), which are not compatible.

Also, why not simply this?

```
void PrintNodes(node *head_p) {
  while (head_p) {
    PrintNodeData(head_p);
    head_p = head_p->next;  // was: head_p++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Because then it would infinitely consume all my memory and try to print nodes that don't exist.

Comment: I replaced `head_p++` with `head_p = head_p->next`

Comment: Ahh! That's absolutely wonderful I _knew_ there was something I wasn't thinking of in my loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just don't. Do the explicit thing.

The long answer is that C++ has a type system and what you're trying to do violates it.

Answer (score 6):

> I have the equivalent if...then...else statement in comments above the conditional statement, I just want to be able to trim it down to one line.

**Don't do it**. First, because it makes your code unnecessarily harder to read. Second, because neither of the types of the two expressions in the conditional operator can be converted to the type of the other expression.

Per paragraph 5.16/3 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] if the second and third operand have different types and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class
>   type, or if both are glvalues of the same value category and the same type except for cv-qualification, an
>   attempt is made to convert each of those operands to the type of the other. [...]

Answer (score 1):

I would use bool, and not use ++ for setting it to true:

```
void PrintNodes(node *head_p) {
  bool done = false;
  while (!done) {
    PrintNodeData(head_p);
    if (head_p->next==NULL)) done = true;
    else head_p++;
  }
}
```

Although isn't `head_p++` supposed to be `head_p= head_p-next`?

Unless, of course you are entering a obfuscated code competition, in which case this would be a good alternative:

```
void PrintNodes(node *head_p) {
  node* done = nullptr;
  while (!done) {
    PrintNodeData(head_p);
    ((head_p->next==NULL) ? done : head_p)++;
  }
}
```

Comment: It could be just as easily. I don't find any difference.

Comment: Which part is your comment commenting on? unless there is a `node* operator++(const node *x) { return x->next; }`, `head_p++;` is not the same as `head_p = head_p->next;` [unless it's a special case where nodes are allocated via an array of objects - but that's not exactly a linked list or anything similar...

Comment: Yes, but don't do that JUST because you can. There is a rule in programming about "no surprises". Stick to doing that for classes/structs that make sense to do it on - if you implement your own big numbers class, iterator class for a list, or similar. But not just "because I can".